# Room Database creating duplicate insertion

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a table named OrderItem. When a button is clicked values are saved to OrderItem table.

```
@Entity(tableName = "order_item_table")
data class OrderItem(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val order_item_id: Long = 0L,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "order_id")
    val orderId: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
    val itemId: Long,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    var quantity: Int
)
```

I am inserting the values through viewmodel.

```
fun saveOrderItemsToDatabase(){
    val itemMap = _menuItemList.value
    Log.d("orderID", "itemMap: $itemMap")
    var itemList = mutableListOf<OrderItem>()
    if(itemMap == null){ return }
    for((itemId,v) in itemMap){
        val orderItem = OrderItem(0, orderId, itemId, v[0])
        itemList.add(orderItem)
    }
    Log.d("orderID", "itemist: $itemList")
    uiScope.launch {
        insertItemsToDatabase(itemList)
    }
}

private suspend fun insertItemsToDatabase(itemList: List<OrderItem>) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        Log.d("orderID", "itemistDisp: $itemList")
        appDB.orderDao.insertOrderItems(itemList)
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I try to fetch the values of OrderItem table in another viewmodel. The values have been inserted twice. I have Logged the item list just before it is been inserted to the table and it doesn't contain any duplicate item.

Code used to fetch from another viewmodel:

```
private suspend fun createCheckoutItem(orderItems: List<OrderItem>): MutableList<CheckoutItem> {
    val itemList = mutableListOf<CheckoutItem>()
    Log.d("orderId", "orderItemsfromDB: $orderItems, size: ${orderItems.size}")
    for (i in orderItems){
        var item = CheckoutItem()
        val currentItem = fetchItem(i.itemId)
        item.orderId = i.orderId
        item.itemCount = i.quantity
        item.itemId = i.itemId
        item.itemName = currentItem.itemName
        item.itemPrice = currentItem.itemPrice
        Log.d("orderId", "$item")
        itemList.add(item)
    }
    return itemList
}

private suspend fun fetchOrderItems(orderId: Long) =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        appDB.orderDao.getAllOrderItems(orderId)
    }
```

Log Messages:

```
2021-05-25 20:49:09.926 2676-2676/com.example.foodie D/orderID: itemMap: {1=[3, 75]}
2021-05-25 20:49:09.927 2676-2676/com.example.foodie D/orderID: itemist: [OrderItem(order_item_id=0, orderId=27, itemId=1, quantity=3)]
2021-05-25 20:49:09.930 2676-2847/com.example.foodie D/orderID: itemistDisp: [OrderItem(order_item_id=0, orderId=27, itemId=1, quantity=3)]
2021-05-25 20:49:10.018 2676-2676/com.example.foodie D/orderId: orderItemsfromDB: [OrderItem(order_item_id=52, orderId=27, itemId=1, quantity=3), OrderItem(order_item_id=53, orderId=27, itemId=1, quantity=3)], size: 2
2021-05-25 20:49:10.022 2676-2676/com.example.foodie D/orderId: CheckoutItem(orderId=27, itemId=1, itemName=Carrot, itemPrice=75, itemCount=3)
2021-05-25 20:49:10.024 2676-2676/com.example.foodie D/orderId: CheckoutItem(orderId=27, itemId=1, itemName=Carrot, itemPrice=75, itemCount=3)
2021-05-25 20:49:10.024 2676-2676/com.example.foodie D/ITEMLIST: checkoutItemList: [CheckoutItem(orderId=27, itemId=1, itemName=Carrot, itemPrice=75, itemCount=3), CheckoutItem(orderId=27, itemId=1, itemName=Carrot, itemPrice=75, itemCount=3)]
```

OrderDao code:

```
@Dao
interface OrderDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertOrderItems(orderItems: List<OrderItem>)

}
```

Comment: Can you please post `orderDao` code?

Comment: I have updated the orderDao code @MayurGajra

Comment: Hey @pepperlove you posted this but removed it, would love to know how you fixed it because I'm having the same exact error logs and there are no other posts about the issue: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XLy6rqYfArYJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160779/corruption-reported-by-sqlite-on-database-while-trying-to-import-to-room-databas

Comment: @Poindess, We should create a db file, for my case I created one using [SQLiteOnline](https://sqliteonline.com/) and downloaded the db file. After that just use `.createFromAsset("databases/final_db.db")` while creating the database.

Comment: @Poindess, I have made the deleted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160779/corruption-reported-by-sqlite-on-database-while-trying-to-import-to-room-databas) visible again. If the solution worked do answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your DAO, you can annotate an OnConflictStrategy that defines how to handle conflicts when inserting data.
More information here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy

For example, IGNORE or REPLACE would work and prevent inserting data twice:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertOrderItems(orderItems: List<OrderItem>)
```